# Replace from something to something

Tags: php, jquery, regex

Have a awesome day.

I have some urls

```
 /notused/purge/page-two.php

 /notused/purge/page-three.php

 /notused/purge/page-four.php
```

I want to replace from "-" to "." means after "-" anything will come like, two or three or four till ".".

And I will use that url in my code.

I am using **jquery** to achieve this.

Can we do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want end url like /notused/purge/page.two.php?

Comment: use split and join

Comment: No, mate ! Url can't be changed. I want to replace that two/three/four, I means to say, that is not fixed from initial url. means anything will come between '-' and '.'. Am I clear ?

Comment: @PranavCBalan : How ? Can you share snippet ?

Comment: @NightWatchman `str.split('-').join('.');`

Comment: @PranavCBalan : Mate, there should be some regex to achieve this right ? I am not sure how ? But I think, we can.

Comment: @NightWatchman : regex can be used

Comment: @PranavCBalan : Mate, I am sorry, it is giving me /notused/purge/page.two.php. My requirement is, e.g say, I pass three, so anything which will come after '-'  and before '.' will be replaced by three.

Comment: @NightWatchman : in case it's four?? o/p => ...... ????

Comment: Mate, url will be output as like this /notused/purge/page-four.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133777/discussion-between-night-watchman-and-pranav-c-balan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace;) method.

```js
var str1 = '/notused/purge/page-two.php';
var str2 = '/notused/purge/page-three.php';
var str3 = '/notused/purge/page-four.php';

function update(str, rep) {
  return str.replace(/-.+\./, '-' + rep + '.');
  // or return str.replace(/-[^.]+\./, '-' + rep + '.');
}

console.log(update(str1, 'three'));
console.log(update(str2, 'two'));
console.log(update(str3, 'four'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will replace the '-' with '.'

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var str = "/notused/purge/page-two.php";
    var test=  str.split('-').join('.');
     alert(test);
  });
 </script>
```

The changed url will be alerted.

Comment: Pardon mate, I need some code, if I pass anything, e.g. three which will replace this url "/notused/purge/page-two.php"; to /notused/purge/page-three.php, if I pass four, it will replace url to "/notused/purge/page-four.php". More precisely, anything after '-' to '.' everything will be replaced by passed string. I want same url, with replacement of anything after '-' to '.'.

Answer (score 0):

please check below you just add your links to links array and you'll get a newArray with your result please check below link or code:

https://jsfiddle.net/fatehjagdeo/g2qzyjef/

```
<script>
    var links=['/notused/purge/page-two.php','/notused/purge/page-three.php','/notused/purge/page-four.php'];
    var newArray=[];

    for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
      var element=links[i].replace("-", "."); 
      newArray.push(element);
    }
    console.log(newArray);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I got from your question is that you want a method to replace *"two"* of **/notused/purge/page-two.php** URL.

So, for that, you can use regex's replace method. I'll add a snippet of it below.

> I am using jquery to achieve this.

Jquery is a great JavaScript library for **DOM traversal and manipulation and animation**, but if you want to do some string manipulation then **Regular Expression** is your best friend.

So, Regex is quite handy when you've to

- search
- match patterns in the string
- replace

in some String.

Ok, for your case, this snippet will work, if not let me know we can create a new Regex based on your requirements.

```js
let regex = /-(.*?)\./g;
let strList = [
  `/notused/purge/page-one.php`,
  `/notused/purge/page-two.php`,
  `/notused/purge/page-three.php`
];
let replaceText = "something";
let match;

for(var i in strList) {
  newURL = replaceInURL(strList[i]);
  console.log(newURL);
}

function replaceInURL(str) {
  var replaceWith = 'something';
  return str.replace(regex, '-' + replaceWith + '.');
}
```